# How do you force a user to sign in on opening a google doc?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've run into a bit of a security issue with a project, and I want to force the user to automatically be logged out at the start of a session or prompt them to sign in with their credentials at the start of a session. For reasons I don't want to disclose, simply logging the active user's e-mail is not sufficient.
I'm having trouble finding a way to do this and was hoping someone on here knows how

Answer (score 0):

### Google Docs is a SaaS product so you can't handle this process

The security of your Google Doc is fully managed by Google. As a best effort you can take a look into [Security best practices for administrator accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9011373) in case you own a Workspace admin account.

The only thing you can do with it is trigger your doc by using simple or installable triggers as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).